# Can anyone actually curse himself?

Tags: curse

If somebody said to one of his parents, "May you see me die in front of you", would his curse Gd forbid become realized ?

Is it also considered "cursing one's parents"? ([Vayikra 20:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0320.htm))

Comment: It is at least "opening the mouth of the 'devil'"

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.8b.9 Rabbi Shimon ben Lakish said, and likewise it was taught in the name of Rabbi Yosei: A person should never open his mouth to Satan https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.60a.24/ https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.19a.20

Comment: Your question seems to focus on "is it possible"? However Pirkei Avot, 2:13 says that one should not be evil before himself. So, it seems to imply that one shouldn't curse himself.

Comment: @DanF , this question in the title is more like "Will the curse uttered upon oneself be realized?" and not a question if it is permitted to curse oneself.

Comment: I guess the best thing is that a Rabbi should decide that 1: the curse can/should NOT be realized, 2 :  the child should not do it again 3: it Should not be not be considered as cursing of one's parents, (but the child should not do it again since it might me considered so)